# handlerbars.js check if list is empty

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there a way in Handlebars.js templating to check if the collection or list is null or empty, before going and iterating through the list/collection?

```
// if list is empty do some rendering ... otherwise do the normal
{{#list items}}

{{/list}}



{{#each items}}

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 232, accepted):

The "each" tag can take an "else" section too. So the simplest form is:

```
{{#each items}}
// render item
{{else}}
// render empty
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That's cool, but doesn't answer the question. If you want a tag to wrap `#each`, like an `<ul>` tag (with `<li>`s inside), you don't want the empty state to be wrapped by the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 263):

If you have something that you want to display *once* and *only if the array has data*, use

```
{{#if items.length}}
    //Render
{{/if}}
```

`.length` will return 0 for empty arrays so we have achieved a real falsey value.

Comment: Both answers are correct and work, and they answer the question. Which was how to display something when there is no data in the array. Not the other way around.

Comment: No i agree, this is the correct answer. It doesn't include a for loop.

Comment: Simple case: I want to render an `<ul>` tag once and an `<li>` tag for each item in the list. If the list is empty I don't even want the `<ul>` to render, and rendering something else like `<p>empty list<p>` inside the `<ul>` doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you are working in Ember.js it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if it has something to do with Ember.js's custom arrays.

Comment: This answer is implementation specific. The [handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#conditionals) specify that `[]` is evaluated as false. 
The answer by @Drejc is the correct answer by handlebar specification.

Comment: thank you dude that is way better solution than registerHelper.

Answer (score 40):

Ok it's simpler than I thought:

```
{{#if items}}
// render items

{{#each items}}
// render item
{{/each}}

{{else}}
// render empty
{{/if}}
```

Comment: If `items` is an empty array (i.e. has a value of `[]`), it will produce a truthy value. Whereas `items.length` produces a falsey value for an empty array. See [@Duane's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381827/handlerbars-js-check-if-list-is-empty/21611066#21611066).

Comment: Huh ... 3 years have past since ... it might be that the implementation has changed or that I simple had no case of [] array. As far as I recall it worked for me.

Comment: You're right. I preemptively commented based on the behavior of native JS' `if`, but the [Handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#conditionals) is very clear: "If its argument returns `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `0`, or `[]`, Handlebars will not render the block." I should have checked the docs first.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check if a collection (cursor) is empty or not, the previous answers won't be useful, instead you must use the `count()` method :

```
{{#if items.count}}
    <p>There is {{items.count}} item(s).</p>
{{else}}
    <p>There is nothing</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: @BasicWolf it does not, count works with cursor, if you have array use length instead.

Comment: This works great to check between an array and an object, and to handle them differently.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who needs to use an {{#each}} on top of {{#if}} (i.e. an if loop inside a for loop). Is they have three different list of arrays.

Using a lookup inside a if statement solves the issue for me. As, the above answers did not solve my issue.

Here is my code,

```
{{#each OtherRandomItems}}

  {{this}}

  {{lookup ../AnotherRandomItems @index}}

  {{#if (lookup ../RandomItems @index)}}
  // render items
  {{else}}
  // render empty
  {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```