# Handlebars.js - {{#each data}} nested in {{#if data}}

Tags: handlebars.js

I would like to be able to do below with Handlebars.js. Is this possible?

```
{{#if data}}

   {{#each data}}
     do something here
   {{/each}}

{{/else}

   No data, sorry!

{/if}
```

Comment: It can be even more succinct actually. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381827/handlerbars-js-check-if-list-is-empty/11597069#11597069

Answer (score 3):

Of course, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/PXQUA/

And you have few typos in your template:

```
{{#if data}}
  {{#each data}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  No data, sorry!
{{/if}}
```